How to increase ScottPlot 5.0 X-axis height for long labels
I am using ScottPlot 5.0.23 for Winforms and plotting a bar chart. The X axis is our sprint names, which are rather long, so the labels look like this

So I added the lines
fp.Plot.Axes.Bottom.TickLabelStyle.Rotation = -45;
fp.Plot.Axes.Bottom.TickLabelStyle.OffsetX = -5;

to put the labels at an angle.
But I'm left with the chart now looking like this

Is there a way to increase the space used by the labels so that they fit? Or is there an alternative way of showing the labels so that they fit better?
P.S. don't judge me for the names of our sprints, it's my team's choice ;-)

I think this link should help you: scottplot.net/cookbook/5.0/CustomizingTicks/RotatedTicksLongLabels/
Especially the axis.MinimumSize stuff, it may be enough to just set a big number rather than needing to measure all the text.

Thanks @Ben, I don't know how I missed this page in the cookbook but it was exactly what I was looking for
